# How to send an array of a complex object with GroovyWS

Tags: soap, groovy, groovyws

I'm about to call a webservice created in C#, that takes a parameter

KmlSystemVariable[] sysVariables

How can I pass a parameter like that using GroovyWS? It doesn't need to have any values, could be an empty array.
Looks like the full class name is Consorte.Pulse.Data.KmlSystemVariable

I enabled logging as described in [GroovyWS and complex requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317453/groovyws-and-complex-requests) to get the namespace for KmlSystemVariable, and it looks like I can create a KmlSystemVariable with:

```
proxy.create("org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.consorte_pulse.KmlSystemVariable")
```

But how do I create an array of KmlSystemVariable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to just wrap your proxied objects into a Groovy list and use it as the parameter. GroovyWS will do the transformation from List to SOAP array for you behind the scenes.

Example:

```
def ksv1 = proxy.create("org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.consorte_pulse.KmlSystemVariable")
def ksv2 = ...
def ksv3 = ...
def list = [ksv1, ksv2, ksv3]
proxy.<some ws method>(list)
```

Comment: Thanks xlson, I will try when I'm back from vacation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.

Comment: That's quite strange, I'm almost certain we do something like this at work. Will check when I get back on thursday.

Comment: This seems to work:  
    def sysvar = webService.create("org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.consorte_pulse.KmlSystemVariable")
    sysvar.name = "foo"
    sysvar.value = "bar"
    def sysvars = webService.create("org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.consorte_pulse.ArrayOfKmlSystemVariable")
    sysvars.kmlSystemVariables << sysvar

Comment: sorry, can't figure out how to format code in comments, or even adding line breaks

Comment: It also looks like I am able to send null as well, as I don't need to pass along any sysvariables. I first thought this didn't work, as I got an error message saying "Specified cast is not valid." But now I found out it was one of the other 14 parameters that was wrong...

Comment: Not quite following your last comment, does it work now or not? :)

Comment: btw, I just recently consumed a different web service, where I needed to create a list with [obj1, obj2, obj3]. But for the web service in this question, I needed to create the special type ArrayOfKmlS‌​ystemVariable. Maybe it depends on if the web service expects a native array or some kind of collection.

Comment: Good to hear! Ah, yeah I think it depends on if "native" soap arrays are used or not.